# how to modify theme components?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to understand how to customize a theme completely.
[material-ui guidelines/docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes) say to check this file:
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/theme-manager.js

So to a custom theme I tried adding a block like:

```
AppTheme = {
  appBar: {
    color: Colors.yellow500,
    textColor: 'white'
  },
```

but that has no effect on the app bar. The rest of the theme variables do work tho.

How do I customize the other [variables in this file](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/theme-manager.js)?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the properties that you mentioned and everything work properly with `appBar`.

The quickest way to check any props in Material-UI theme is to see the

[storybook-addon-material-ui](https://sm-react.github.io/storybook-addon-material-ui/?theme-ind=0&theme-sidebar=true&theme-full=true&selectedKind=Material%20App&selectedStory=Sign%20In%20page&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=sm%2Fstorybook-addon-material-ui%2Fmaterial-panel) demo page!

(You can find `appBar` props at the right sidebar and play with colors.)

so it should work!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14273773)

Comment: Ok I changed it